# Google Plus Invite on Android

Tags: android, google-plus

I just used the following link http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/ for Google Plus integration in my android app and it worked fine. But when I tried to invite users to my app via Google plus, I was not able to do that. Is it possible to invite google plus friends to my app?

I used this to get the friend list

```
@Override
    public void onPeopleLoaded(ConnectionResult status, PersonBuffer personBuffer, String nextPageToken) {
        switch (status.getErrorCode()) {

        case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
            try {
                int count = personBuffer.getCount();
                Log.e("", "count : " + count);
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    Log.e("NAME", "" + personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName());
                }
            } finally {
                personBuffer.close();
            }

            break;

        case ConnectionResult.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED:
            mPlusClient.disconnect();
            mPlusClient.connect();
            break;

        default:
            Log.e("TAG", "Error when listing people: " + status);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: WHy not describe your problem a bit more detailed? Your problem description and you ability to debug seem to end with " I was not able to do that". You show some code to retrieve the friend list, and the what happened then?

Comment: And what do you mean by invite people to your app?

Comment: I want to send a message to gplus friend , Like "Try the "abc" app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share to Google+ from an Android app you will want to follow this [guideline](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/).

Add a share button to your layout.

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/share_button"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Share on Google+"
/>
```

In your activity, configure your button's OnClickListener to share when clicked.

```
Button shareButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share_button);
shareButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // Launch the Google+ share dialog with attribution to your app.
      Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
          .setType("text/plain")
          .setText("Welcome to the Google+ platform.")
          .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
          .getIntent();

      startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is sharing and inviting friends same thing in case of google plus?